# How do I / what is the best way to remove all users from a Discord Role in python?

Tags: python, discord

total I'm a total discord/python noob, I don't really have any code to show as I don't even know where to start. All I'm trying to do is remove everyone from a certain discord role.

Lets say the role is, "Warrior" and there are 5 people in it, I don't want to delete the role entirely, instead I want to just remove all 5 people from it. I guess in theory I could delete the entire role and then create it again, let me know your thoughts and the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite the lengthy response, but I recommend reading the entire thing.

StackExchange is a community where people post and discuss code. With all do respect, I can guarantee you that nobody here, including me, is going to write you code if we cannot see what you have tried or any existing code.

You will definitely have better luck on this site if you have a relevant product that people can look at to find errors and/or help you build upon it.

In the meantime, check out the Unofficial User Discord API Server here: https://discordapp.com/invite/discord-API

When I was in your shoes, this discord server was extremely helpful with answering any questions about the Discord API as 99.9% of the people there know exactly what your issue is and how to solve it. People are always online to take your questions as you build your code.

If you need help with starting your code, the basic steps go as follows:

1. Pip install the discord API
2. Create a bot user on https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro
3. Use the bot token to write your code

Because I don't know exactly what progress you have made on your bot thus far, I just strung together some wireframe code in python to get started.

```html
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
description = "desc"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', description=description)
#startup command
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')
#category of main commands
class Main_Commands():
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
#ping command test
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await bot.say("pong")
#when the user types in ?ping, the bot will return "pong"
#This is an example of a simple command in this language
#RunBot
bot.run("TOKEN GOES HERE")
# (C) 2017
# All rights reserved
# Any part of this program may be used and/or modified at the users discretion
```

Anyways, I hope this response helped you. If you need any help from me, please feel free to message me at ABoostED#6865 on Discord and I will try to get back to whenever my schedule permits.

Happy Coding!!

P.S. check out the API Reference http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html